# Galaxy 4 - Remove widget from homescreen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, app-widgets, home-screen

I have a picture from my gallery in front of my wallpaper on my homescreen, it  got there by accident while in my pocket.  how can I get rid of this pic so all I see is my wallpaper? I've tried changing the wallpaper but the picture is still in front with the wallpaper behind it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing it, but what you describe sounds like you've added a *home screen widget* (a.k.a. *appwidget*). Long-press the widget to pick it up, and a delete icon will appear (it looks like a bin or an X). Drag-and-drop the widget onto the delete icon.